# I need help getting a xmlhttprequest in cordova working

Tags: cordova, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get a simple xmlhttprequest (GET) working in Cordova. I have the following meta tag in the index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

And then for the config.xml I have the following:

```
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```

Then, in index.js, I have the following:

```
hitTheNetz: function() {
    alert("Hit the Netz Boyz!");
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
    oReq.open("GET", "http://10.0.0.56:8080/test");
    oReq.send();     
},
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
document.getElementById("testRequest").addEventListener("click", this.hitTheNetz);
},
```

and this in the initialize function:

```
    document.getElementById("testRequest").addEventListener("click", this.hitTheNetz);
```

I've tested the code in a web page - it works if I hit the page from the phone, so I know the code is working in a browser... It looks like I'm missing something basic in the Cordova app, and I'm not sure how to find it or fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the answer, but had to take a detour through NativeScript to find it.

Android 8+ disables sending cleartext(http) requests. You have to enable it. Where? Glad you asked.

In the config.xml, change your 'widget' line add the following:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

then make sure you have the following below:

```
  <platform name="android">
      <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
      <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
  </edit-config>
  </platform>
```

that should clear it up. No idea why this is not the first hit for recent queries on this issue. Hope this helps!